# Sequelize associate a table without defining its schema

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Lets say I have a table in the DB called departments, In my code I don't need to interact directly with it and its schema is defined as a part of another service.

I want to make a new table called employees that will have a foreign key from departments.

Is there a way to make this association (referencing the table) without needing to defining the table schema again in my project?

Comment: I believe you are talking about  micro-services here, If you have two or more separate services with there individual DB. The main point of making micro -services architecture is to have lean and individual dedicated separation  functionality. So IMHO you don't need to have foreign key constraints in between two DB/services. However you need to manage that part manually on application level . Please correct me if I misunderstood you.

Comment: @VipulPatil You are correct. But in general is there a way to reference a model without creating defining its schema in sequelize? I have done it with mongoose but not sure about sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to define an association between two tables one with a model defined in Sequelize and the other with no model defined in Sequelize.

To define an association between two models you must define their respective models in Sequelize.